# ABR Analyze Buffer overflow - Klockwork issue

Tags: c, klocwork

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define RPTE_TE_TNL (x)  x->pTeTnlInfo
#define RSVPTE_TNL_NAME(x)  x->au1TnlName
#define LENGTH 32
#define STRLEN(s) strlen((const char *)(s))

typedef char INT1;

unsigned short length;

struct _tTeTnlInfo
{
    unsigned char       au1TnlName[LENGTH];
}

length = unsigned short( STRLEN ((INT1 *)RSVPTE_TNL_NAME (RPTE_TE_TNL (pRsvpTeTnlInfo))) );
```

---

Klockwork gives an error for above line -
ABR Analyze Buffer overflow, array index of 'pRsvpTeTnlInfo->pTeTnlInfo->au1TnlName' may be out of bounds. Array 'pRsvpTeTnlInfo->pTeTnlInfo->au1TnlName' of size 32 may use index value(s) 0..INT_MAX-1.

I am not able to find out the root cause, why klocwork gives this error. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Why the result of RSVPTE_TNL_NAME is cast to (INT1*)? Maybe Klocwork has a problem with this cast, which does not seem necessary. Of course it is hard to say since we do not know the definitions of INT1 and STRLEN.

Comment: updated the value of INT1 and STRLEN

Comment: I am not sure how smart Klocwork can be, but maybe it does not like using strlen on au1TnlName, since there is no guarantee that au1TnlName is null terminated. Try strnlen if available, or maybe write your own strnlen similar to strlen, but with additional length argument, so it never goes outside of the buffer.

Comment: you find it more readable with all the defines? why dont you just split it up to make it more clear or just look at the code spit out after the preprocessor ran.

Comment: Above code is not written for compilation, It is for just understanding the issue.

Comment: This code is not valid C.